# Program to find a pair with the given number in array

Tags: c, arrays, sum

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num[] = { 6, 8, 4, -5, 7, 9 };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++) {
            sum = num[i] + num[j];
            if (sum == 15) {
                printf("%d\n%d", num[i], num[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to find a pair of numbers in the array with a sum of 15. The expected output is 6 & 9. But I'm getting output as 6, 98, 7. What is wrong?

**EDIT**: The issue was not giving a new line after the first result. Sorry.

Comment: `8 + 7 = 15`

I don't see the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue was not giving a new line after the first result.

replace

> ```
> printf("%d\n%d",num[i],num[j]);
> ```

by

```
printf("%d,%d\n",num[i],num[j]);
```

Comment: Yeah,got that.Stupid mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

i find nothing wrong here `9+6=15` and `8+7=15`
and also in printf instead of

`printf("%d\n%d",num[i],num[j]);`

use

`printf("%d %d\n",num[i],num[j]);`

you will get well suited output